# How to remove one legend option for Semi circle donut?

Tags: highcharts, legend, pie-chart

I need to leave just one legend option for this chart.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi8S4.png)

My code:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        innerSize: '60%',
        colorByPoint: true,
    showInLegend: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Chrome',
          //showInLegend: true, ----dosen't work
            y: 70.67,
        }, {
            name: 'Edge',
          //showInLegend: true, ----dosen't work
            y: 29.33
        } ]
    }]
});
```

My demo: https://jsfiddle.net/artemShakun/otr34bm9/32/

I've tried to add showInLegend=true/false in series.data but it doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me when I set `showInLegend=false` in your jsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible by using API options, but you can add this simple plugin below to achieve what you want.

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'getAllItems', function(proceed) {
    const items = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    items.pop();
    return items;
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ca94jsfm/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts